# AjaxControlToolkit LineChart doesn't work with 3 values in IE11 or Edge

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using the AjaxControlToolkit in an ASP.NET WebForms application and I have a line chart with 3 values. 
I noticed that if a line has 3 X-axis values and  only one line series that in IE it doesn't draw the last item but displays it below the grid.
This is only for IE11 or Edge. In Chrome it shows correctly.

I am using the latest AjaxControlToolkit version 15.1.3 released Aug 2015.

Here is the code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="LineChart.aspx.cs" Inherits="LineChart2.LineChart" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>        
    <form id="form1" runat="server">  
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"/>
    <div>

        <ajaxToolkit:LineChart ID="LineChart1" runat="server"
            ChartType="Basic" Visible="false">
        </ajaxToolkit:LineChart>
    </div>
</form>
```

CodeBehind:

```
using System;

namespace LineChart2
{
    public partial class LineChart : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            LineChart1.ChartTitle = "Test";
            LineChart1.CategoriesAxis = "X1, X2, X3";
            LineChart1.Series.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.LineChartSeries { Name = "Test", Data = new decimal[] { 12, 34, 67 } });
            LineChart1.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Screen Output]

Problem can be clearly seen above

If I change the two lines to show 4 items

```
    LineChart1.CategoriesAxis = "X1, X2, X3, X4";
    LineChart1.Series.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.LineChartSeries { Name = "Test", Data = new decimal[] { 12, 34, 67, 87 } });
```

Then all 4 items are shown in the LineChart.

When I add two series of 3 items each instead of one:

```
LineChart1.Series.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.LineChartSeries { Name = "Test", Data = new decimal[] { 6, 6, 6 } });
 LineChart1.Series.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.LineChartSeries { Name = "Test", Data = new decimal[] { 7, 7, 7 } });
```

Then both series show correctly

So the issue is only happens when there is

- 1 series
- The series  only has 3 items. Values can be anything
- Happens in IE11 and Edge browsers

My Question: How do I fix my code to work with one series of 3 items in IE11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this on the AjaxControlToolkit Forum as an issue and they have acknowledged and fixed it to be released in the next release.

[Issue Log Item](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/27955)